# Post a picture in my application's album with Facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos

I have an application on Facebook where I select a picture and I can upload to an album associated with the application.

I found some code about it, but until now, I could upload only to my personal account.

With this code I can get all the album details of the application:

```
$facebook->api('/app_id/albums?access_token='.$acces_token);
```

That's cool, I get a list, but after this, I do the following:

```
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$acces_token, 'post', $photo_details);
```

And I always get the following exeption:
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid ID for album owner thrown in

What is the problem?!
Maybe I don't have the right permissions? Or am I missing something?

I even tried this:

```
$create_album = $facebook->api('/app_id/albums?access_token='.$acces, 'post', $album_details);
$album_uid = $create_album['id'];
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos?access_token='.$acces, 'post', $photo_details);
```

Comment: Hi András, were you able to do this?  I'm now trying to do the same thing.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Did you find the reason for the error? I am also stuck with it..
I am unable determine.. there are too many access_tokens.
1. for the app, 1 for the page..

Answer (score 0):

Try this!! it creates a new album and then it posts a photo in that specific album..

```
$post_login_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/yourapp/thefile";
   $album_name = 'name of Album';
   $album_description = 'something about album';


   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
   //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
   if(empty($code))
     {
       $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
       . "&scope=publish_stream";
       echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . 
       "'</script>");
   } 
   else {
     $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
     . "access_token?"
     . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
     . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
     . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
     . "&code=" . $code;
     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
     $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

     // Create a new album
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
     . "access_token=". $access_token;

     $postdata = http_build_query(
     array(
      'name' => $album_name,
      'message' => $album_description
        )
      );
     $opts = array('http' =>
     array(
      'method'=> 'POST',
      'header'=>
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content' => $postdata
      )
     );
     $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
     $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, 
       $context));

     // Get the new album ID
     $album_id = $result->id;

     //Show photo upload form and post to the Graph URL
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id
       . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;
     echo '<html><body>';
     echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
     .$graph_url. ' "method="POST">';
     echo 'Adding photo to album: ' . $album_name .'<br/><br/>';
     echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
     echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
     echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
     echo '<input name="message" type="text"
        value=""><br/><br/>';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload"  /><br/>';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</body></html>';
  }

 ?>
```

Comment: Thx, but It doesn't do what I want, this will create it on my PERSONAL page, and what I want is to create it on the application page :)